# html5 video doesn't play on android without controls

Tags: android, html, video

Goodday,

I have a question in regards to a video resource I use on a website. I have made a fiddle for it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/cgzLkqqc/

html

```
<div id="video_container">
  <video poster="" width="500" id="showReelVid" loop preload>
    <source src="http://hemlockdevelopment.net/media/showreel_jurgen_reigman.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video :(.
  </video>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var showReelVid = document.getElementById("showReelVid"); 

showReelVid.play();
```

Now this works fine as intended on the web, but it does not seem to work on android phones without adding controls to the video tag. Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here cause I see it does work on other sites that use a fullscreen video without controls.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only video elements with the muted attribute set to true are allowed to autoplay on Android and iOS devices.

The following example would autoplay:

```
<div id="video_container">
    <video poster="" width="500" id="showReelVid" muted autoplay loop preload>
        <source src="http://hemlockdevelopment.net/media/showreel_jurgen_reigman.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video :(.
    </video>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/16j6851z/

---

If you require audio, have the video play on click (or with other user input) instead:

**HTML**

```
<div id="video_container">
  <video poster="" width="500" id="showReelVid" loop preload>
    <source src="http://hemlockdevelopment.net/media/showreel_jurgen_reigman.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video :(.
  </video>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var showReelVid = document.getElementById("showReelVid");
showReelVid.onclick = function() {
  showReelVid.play();
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p8cmv1vc/